# Kubernetes Pod - ssh time out inside docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, ssh, kubernetes-helm

<env> 
local machine(mac Big Sur) 
minikube(Darwin 11.4, minikube v1.22.0) 
minikube driver = hiperkit
helm chart 
airflow 1.10.11 
amazon EMR 
VPN(no proxie)

inside Kubernetes Pods, Container can not ssh into remote server(AWS EMR for this case)

while, it is possible for git-sync container to ssh into github, static container(for this case, airflow scheduler) can't ssh into Amazon EMR server with appropriate key.

for example, outside minikube, my local mac terminal is able to connect EMR with no problem(every network is inside VPN starting 172.x.x.x)

one more strange thing is, same Kubernetes env on Amazon EKS(production), there is no ssh connection problem on same container(airflow scheduler pod - airflow container). I am literally able to ssh on a container docker bash shell command.

Also, inside minikube, curl command works such as myip.com. So only ssh is blocked (I tried from plain docker, and ssh had no problem) So, only minikube docker had a SSH connection problem.

I suspect port problem, but on EKS, there was no ssh problem with exact same helm chart.
Only local minikube fails.

I share my logs, I will appreciate any answers. Thanks.

-my container route table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

- netstat

```
airflow@airflow-test-scheduler-76869c5546-svnnk:/opt/airflow/dags$ netstat -anp |grep 22
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:49228        10.109.98.113:5432      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:36148        52.78.231.108:22        TIME_WAIT   -                   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     152204   69/airflow schedule  /tmp/pymp-6zqm69hn/listener-uqwa_n0n
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     152208   61/airflow schedule  /tmp/pymp-gieffrz0/listener-s8z5z1_k
```

- debugging

```
airflow@airflow-test-scheduler-76869c5546-svnnk:/opt/airflow/dags$ ssh -v -i emr-pa.pem hadoop@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal port 22: Connection timed out
```

after some research, I tried nmap for host and my minikube cluster.
this is following report from nmap

- minikube

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-23 11:06 UTC
Nmap scan report for host.minikube.internal (192.168.64.1)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh

Nmap scan report for 192-168-64-2.kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local (192.168.64.2)
Host is up (0.036s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 112.09 seconds
```

- host

```
Nmap scan report for ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal (172.24.4.254)
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal (xxx.xxx.x.xxx) are filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the other away to solve this problem.
If you use `minikube start --driver=docker`  instead of `--driver=hyperkit` then ssh port naturally opens. I still can not find why 'hyperkit' has blocked `ssh` through Kubernetes VM but this might be one reason.

this: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8162
and this : https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#possible-workarounds

Don't forget to turn on `Kubernetes enable` on your docker when you change `--dirver=docker` mode